# Trying to loop with a simple for loop and return the operation with a console.log

Tags: javascript

Been trying to loop through this arr array and return the operation result, I know I'm missing something I just don't remember what. it is returning the array, not the operation. (i'm having a lot of problems with loop so please be patient).

```js
let arr = [225, 555, 44];

// const calcTip = (bill) => bill > 50 && bill < 300 ? bill * 0.15 : bill * 0.20;

function calcTip(bill) {
    for (let index = 0; index < bill.length; index++) {
       if (bill[index] > 50 && bill[index] < 300) {
         bill[index] * 0.15;
       } else if (bill[index] < 50 && bill[index] > 300) {
         bill[index] * 0.20;
       }
    }
};
tip = calcTip (arr);
console.log(tip);
```

Comment: You have to assign the result to the array element `bill[index] = ...`

Comment: What do you think you're missing and why?  At a glance, this code doesn't even *do* anything because (1) the function is never called and, more importantly, (2) the result of the multiplication is never used.

Comment: Or you can use the auto-assignment operator. `*=`

Comment: Regarding the edit... *"it is returning the array, not the operation."* - The function shown isn't **returning** anything.  It looks like it's attempting to modify the array in-place though, but a typo (noted in comments above) prevents that.  Or perhaps intends to aggregate a new value and return that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is a mistake in your boolean check

`else if (bill[index] < 50 && bill[index] > 300)`

It can't be less than 50 and greater than 300 at the same time.
Either replace `&&` with `||` or just use else instead - going from your ternary comment, this is probably what you wanted to have.

Second problem is that if you expect a return value out of the function, it will not work since you're not returning anything.

That said, the array is being changed in place, so could just replace

```
tip = calcTip (arr);
console.log(tip);
```

With

```
calcTip(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

If you do need a new array, just use `.map`

```
const tips = arr.map((amount) => amount > 50 && amount < 300 ? amount * 0.15 : amount * 0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the tip value (i assume that is what you are trying to do). You should create a tip array (so you have a tip for each bill) and pass it to the function and then:

tip[index] = bill[index] * 0.15;

Comment: i`m basicaly trying to make this exercise : "Write a function 'calcTip' that takes any bill value as an input and returns
the corresponding tip."
i already did it with one value and an arrow function. now i have to do it with an array, and to do that i need to make the operation for each number in the array.

Comment: If you have an array of N bills, then you will need an array of N tips. One tip for each bill. So the fuctions would be: `calcTip(tips, bills);` and the logic would be the one i wrote in the answer.